# Output redirection to multiple files

Tags: python, bash, redirect

I need to run a python script for multiple input files and for each one, I want to generate a new corresponding output file (e.g. for input_16jun.txt I want the output file to be 16jun_output.txt). I tried doing something like:

```
nohup python script.py input_{16..22}jun.txt > {16..22}jun_output.txt &
```

But I keep getting "ambiguous redirect" error. Does anyone know how to fix this? Or any other better approach?

Comment: Try this - nohup python script.py input_{16..22}jun.txt | tee  {16..22}jun_output.txt &

Comment: Still the same error :/

Comment: just updated. Try it if it works

Comment: Looks like that ran the script for only one input file and stored the same output in every output file

Comment: i thought your input and output file name is changing in each iteration ? tee would overwrite content in file.

Comment: Yes, that's what's supposed to happen but that's not what actually happened. All the generated output files (16jun_output.txt/17jun_output.txt..) had the same exact output.

Comment: is it possible to delete nohup.out at the end of  each iteration ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118118/discussion-between-ion20-and-indra-uprade).

Answer (score 2):

Looping over each input file like this with bash should work.

```
for f in input_*.txt; do python script.py $f > "${f:6:-4}"_output.txt; done
```

Alternatively if you want to do the loop in a python script.

```
import glob
import os

input_files = glob.glob("input_*.txt")

for f in input_files:
    os.system("python script.py {} > {}_output.txt".format(f,f.split("input_")[1].rstrip(".txt")))
```

If you want to run script.py in parallel (rather than sequentially) you can also consider using the python `multiprocessing` package.